# Repadmin and DNScmd

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, replication

A little query really in terms of the usage of Repadmin and DNScmd when forcing replication of DNS zones. I'm currently studying for my 70-640 (Active Directory Exam) and was wondering what the difference is in terms of utilizing the said tools for forcing DNS replication.

I've seen questions which reference forcing replication with the answers varying between these tools and was wondering when and why you would use either one specifically.

Perhaps my understanding is incorrect: Use repadmin to force replication for any Active Directory integrated zones and use DNScmd to force zone tranfers for non-AD integrated DNS zones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah. What you suspect is correct.